# How to extract fields from an RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am not very good with RDDs, please help me extract 2 fields from an RDD, and create a new simpler RDD that I can then manipulate / convert etc.

1 sample RDD record below. (This is using scala spark)

```
RF_RDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)] = ScalaEsRDD[32] at RDD at AbstractEsRDD.scala:37
(AXObQ5JaIXI8icz9PfkJ,{"Indicator":{"Type":{"@type":"Vocabs:IndicatorTypeVocab-1.1","value":"Domain"},"@timestamp":"2008-07-19","Description":{"value":"Current risk: Malicious.Triggers 1 of 47 rules"},"Valid_Time_Position":{"End_Time":{"@precision":"second","value":"2003-07-13"},"Start_Time":{"@precision":"second","value":"2005-07-13"}},"Producer":{"Description":{"value":"Recorded Future"},"References":{"Reference":{"value":"https://app.sdsdsdsds.com"}}},"Confidence":{"Description":{"value":"score"},"Value":{"value":"65"}},"@type":"indicator:IndicatorType","Indicated_TTP":{"TTP":{"@timestamp":"2005-07-16T17","Description":{"value":"1 sighting2"},"@type":"ttp:TTPType","Title":{"value":"Risk Rule: recent"},"@id":"RF:TTP-9fsfdf fdfn-fdsfsdf-fds-fdsf"},"Confidence":{"Value":{"@type":"stixVocabs:HighMediumLowVocab-1.0","value":"Medium"}}},"Title":{"value":"Domain cpcalendars.appconfirmationcovid19.giize.com"},"@id":"F:Indicator-7f70e7b0-66cc-3c80-a586-86bab718dc25","Observable":{"Object":{"@id":"F:DomainName-sfdfs-f4rfwrg-f4frfwrf","Properties":{"@type":"DomainNameObj:DomainNameObjectType","Value":{"value":"cpcalendars.appconfirmationcovid19.giize.com","@condition":"Equals"}}},"@id":"F:Observable-fs42f2-24frfwdf-24-wf"}},"X_Package":{"@timestamp":"2003-07-19","@version":"1.2","@id":"RF:Package-fsdfsdf-fs322fw-f23wdfs-","S_Header":{"Description":{"value":"Yahoo-google"}}},"_vis":"dfs&dsfds&da"})
```

I tried something like this but it did not work:

```
val RDD2 = RDD1.map(r => (r._2.getOrElse("Reference", "").toString))

RDD2.take(3)
```

Ultimately trying to extract "Reference" and "@id"

Thank you!

Comment: What is the output of RDD2.take(2)? How did you create the RF_RDD?  Please provide a minimal reproducible example so that we can assist you better. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

With the output you added here, It looks like RF_RDD is a key-value pair RDD where both keys and values are string.
Therefore, `r._2` is a string.

```scala
val RDD2 = RDD1.map(r => (r._2.getOrElse("Reference", "").toString))
```

Try parsing `r._2` with a suitable JSON parser or map to a model to extract the nested object(s) and return. Since you need 2 values (id and reference), return it as a key-value pair `(id, reference)`